# navbar full-width of screen bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm trying to create a basic navbar but it's not fitting the full width of my page nor is it responding to any color classes, her's the code for my header

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="newPage.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Any idea of what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. You must not have written any 'script'

```
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
      <!-- Brand/logo -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="bird.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
      </a>

      <!-- Links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
```